# Why father is called "dada" and not "fafa"

Tags: etymology

Read the words below :

- Mother - mama - mammy
- Father - dada - daddy

Why is father not called *fafa* or *faddy*?

Comment: As a sidenote, father is from the old Norse faðir (where the ð (Eth/Edd) has the 'th' sound).  The Eth has been dropped from use in the alphabets of Danish, Norwegian and Swedish, but is still found in Faroese and Icelandic. However, kids do call their fathers 'fafa' in Denmark, or just 'far'[fah] (Far is the Danish word for Father).

Comment: I got a chuckle out of "faddy." I cannot figure out how to pronounce it that wouldn't be immediately offensive

Comment: What about *papa*?

Comment: Or *baba* in Mandarin Chinese, among other languages (including English: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/baba)

Comment: Someone pointed out (trying to refute the claim that certain words are innate to the human brain) that "mama" means *father* in Georgian.

Comment: It might be interesting to note, that a sound similar 'pa' is used throughout the world for father and a sound similar to 'ma' is used for mother.

Comment: There's a Celtic father god - the Dagda

Answer (score 29):

The term *dad* has [origins](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dad) in children's speech:

> recorded from c.1500, but probably much older, from child's speech, nearly universal and probably prehistoric (cf. Welsh *tad*, Ir. *daid*, Czech, L., Gk. *tata*, Lith. *tete*, Skt. *tatah* all of the same meaning)

[*Daddy*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=daddy) is the diminutive of this:

> c.1500, colloquial dim. of *dad*, with -*y*

The [OED](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/1446/whats-the-origin-of-the-word-dad) quoted here adds more, saying:

> Occurs from the 16th c. (or possibly 15th c.), in representations of rustic, humble, or childish speech, in which it may of course have been in use much earlier, though it is not given in the Promptorium or Catholicon, where words of this class occur.
>
> **Of the actual origin we have no evidence: but the forms dada, tata, meaning 'father', originating in infantile or childish speech, occur independently in many languages**. It has been assumed that our word is taken from Welsh tad, mutated dad, but this is very doubtful; the Welsh is itself merely a word of the same class, which has displaced the original Celtic word for 'father' = Ir. athair.
>
> A childish or familiar word for father: originally ranking with mam for mother, but now less typically childish. Cf. daddy.
>
> ?a1500 Chester Pl. (Shaks. Soc.) I. 43 Cayme. I will..Speake with my dadde and mam also..Mamme and dadd, reste you well! [Of uncertain date: the MS. is only of 1592. Harl. MS. of 1607 reads (ii. 678) 'sire and dam', (ii. 681) 'father and mother'.]
>
> 1553 Wilson Rhet. 31 Bryngyng forthe a faire child unto you..suche a one as shall call you dad with his swete lispyng wordes.

So *dad* or *daddy* stems from baby talk. This makes sense—*f* is a [difficult sound for babies to say](http://www.babycenter.com/404_should-i-worry-that-my-2-year-old-mispronounces-many-words_69451.bc), but "harder" sounds like *d* are easier. Note, however, that just because many cultures share the same-sounding word (dada, tad, tata), this does not mean that one can make a clear distinction of *origin*. Though [*tata*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tata#Latin) means *dad*, it does not provide substantial evidence that *dad* is from *tata*. As the OED points out, the form occurred *independently* in many languages.

Comment: For babies everything starts as gaga (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VwgkT34g61w).

Comment: Yeah, people assume the baby's saying what they want it to say, so that's what they make their words! :P

Comment: @samthere good point. It does explain why so many languages have some variant on "dada" that seem to have developed separately. People heard the babbling a put a name to it.

Comment: With our daughter, momma, bobba and dadda were the first three sounds she made, in that order. No idea who this Bobba guy is, but when I find him...

Comment: Another point along these lines is that, in my experience, babytalk regresses towards reduplication. My two year-old pronounces "Captain America" (a fixture in our household) as "Kukka Mukka".

Answer (score 4):

It originated from Latin word for father, Tata. In time it became dada instead.

Source:  [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tata#Latin)

Comment: Interesting. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tata#Latin

Comment: Unless you have evidence that it actually did come from Latin (which the sources quoted by the other answerers have all missed) this is unfounded speculation. -1.

Comment: @Colin Pekka did that for me.

Comment: @Pekka Can I use your sorce to edit my answer?

Comment: @Chaos sure, go ahead.

Comment: @ColinFine My source (EtymOnline) does mention the Latin connection--"L., Gk. tata"--but the OED didn't mention it.

Comment: If anybody has any problems with this question, it will be a good thing to write the reason here why. Don't just downvote. I want reasons. Isn;t the whole point of criticism is to make the answer better?

Comment: Your answer presumes that "dada" came directly from "tata", which is not supported by the sources you cite.

Comment: The Latin word for 'father' is pater, not tata. As others have mentioned, many languages have words for father beginning pa-, ba- or da-.

Answer (score 3):

The NOAD, for *dada* reports the following note:

> ORIGIN late 17th century: perhaps imitative of a young child's first syllables (see dad).

The note at *dad* says:

> ORIGIN mid 16th century: perhaps imitative of a young child's first syllables *da, da*.